# Determining when Ax=b is consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations, satisfiability

Let A = $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -3 &2\\ 
-2 & 5 &-1 \\ 
 3&-3  &-12 
\end{bmatrix}$ and b = $\begin{bmatrix}
b_{1}\\ 
b_{2}\\ 
b_{3}
\end{bmatrix}$.

Determine if the equation *Ax* = *b* is consistent for all possible $b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}$. If the equation is not consistent for all possible $b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}$, give a description of the set of all *b* for which the equation is consistent.

I know that the solution is that the equation is consistent for all $b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}$ satisfying $9b_{1}+6b_{2}+b_{3}=0$ via an answer key but I don't understand how to get there. I found that the reduced row echelon form of the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &-7 \\0 
 &1  &-3 \\0 
 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$, but if anything, doesn't that tell me that the ratio between $b_{1}$ and $b_{3}$ is $-7$?

To extrapolate this to more general problems, since it seems I lack an understanding of systems of equations like these, what does $A$ tell me about the system as a whole? I thought that $A$ told me about the ratio between the coefficients to $x$ that satisfy $Ax=b$, if that makes sense. Why am I wrong, or what am I missing?

Comment: Compute the $RHS$ corresponding to this echelon form, and light will shine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The augmented matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -3 &2 & b_1\\ 
-2 & 5 &-1 & b_2\\ 
 3&-3  &-12 &b_3\end{array}
\right]$$

is row reduced to$$ \left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -3 &2 & b_1\\ 
0 & -1 &3 &2b_1+ b_2\\ 
 0&0  &0 &9b_1+6b_2+b_3\end{array}
\right]$$

Since the first three elements of the third row are $0$, for consistency you need the last row to be completely  $0$  so you have $$9b_1+6b_2+b_3=0$$

Answer (score 3):

Do the row reduction on the augmented matrix
$$
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & -3 &2 & b_1\\ 
-2 & 5 &-1 & b_2\\ 
 3&-3  &-12 &b_3\end{array}
\right]
$$
instead.